# How to get a steady 12 V output from 12-15 V source?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, 12v

I am working on a project with a variable voltage input 12 - 14.6 V.

I need a constant 12 V output to power some 12 V LED strips. I’m running this through a home automation board and will be controlling the LEDs with a logic level N channel MOSFET.

I would ideally like the variable input to the board and be able to connect 5 m of LED strips (2 wire + and -) to a seperate output on the board and power them this way as it will look tidier.

Should I

1. Run a trace from the board 12-14 V in to the 12 V LED output connector and PWM from the negative?
2. Go through a 12 V voltage regulator through a trace to the LED +- outputs?
3. Forget about regulating the 12 V as the voltage is within range of the FET and just connect the negative side of the leds to the board and have a seperate supply for the LED?

12 V should be the minimum though it may drop below that in which case the LEDs would just be dimmer. My 5/3.3 V circuits are powered via a buck converter so I'm not worried about them as should be good well below the minimum.

Current wise I'm thinking it will likely be around 5 A though that doesn't leave much room for error, 10 A is an 8 mm trace which is ridiculous. I had planned to use 12 V relays though they only permit 120% vmax so will probably either use MOSFETS or 5 V regulated relays.

Comment: Generally LEDs are driven by a constant current source, if 12V is the minimum you expect your power supply to be able to provide (as far as voltage, if it swings up to 15V does it matter?) then I think you'd really only need to be concerned with the amount of current you're attempting to drive through the LEDs at that voltage.

Comment: A buck regulator, probably a PFET one which can go to 100 % duty cycle.

Comment: @robbrown, What is the source? what are the LED's?

Comment: @VoltageSpike source is a vehicle battery voltage range 12v-14.8v
LEDs are simple two wire strips they run about 7w/m at 12v

Comment: Can/will the vehicle battery ever be discharged lower than 12V?  (Think: power goes out, lights are still on, etc.)  A buck/boost, sepic, or other such converter can give 12V from higher *and* lower input.  If an ignition and alternator are involved, then all of this must tolerate supply spikes of 100VDC or so.

Comment: @rdtsc it can be discharged to 11v the whole circuit is powered through a seperate dcdc charger connected to the ignition so this is isolated from the alternator spikes

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is a simple LDO. You could buy one or make one with a P channel MOSFET and a differential pair and some voltage reference.

Comment: I agree. At 14 V in, we are talking about ~86 % efficiency anyway.

Comment: a regulated 12v would be very helpful as I could use it to trigger the mosfets and ideally the relays though I'd have to keep an eye on the thermals depending on the current

Comment: the problem is the ammount of current I would need through the LDO the main reason i want to do this is so that a 12v light will stay at the same brightness regardless of input voltage of 12-14.6v

Comment: @robbrown92 .How much current? the linear will burn up to 2.6 watts per amp .If your current is huge then I have done buck converters that will go to D of 100% .to do this dont use a chip.

Comment: I've decided to just use the raw variable input unregulated. the led strips can handle the higher voltage and I don't have space on the board for another buck converter. I will be powering the 12v relays through a ULN2003 most likely and with the voltage drop across the protection diodes it should bring the voltage within the 14.4v tolerance, though I am also still considering using 5v relays as they will likely be more reliable.